# duplicate key value violates unique constraint in django

Tags: python, django

I have function for creating new user in django as follows:

```
def initialize(username, password, email, title, firstName, lastName,  telephoneNumber, mobileNumber, smsActive, for_company_id = 1):
    sUsername = username.lower()
    if len(username) > 30:
        sUsername = username[:30].lower()
    user = User.objects.create_user(sUsername, email, password, last_login=datetime.datetime.now())
    user.first_name = firstName
    user.last_name = lastName
    user.save()
    userProfile = UserProfile(user = user, title = title, telephone = telephoneNumber, mobile = mobileNumber, smsActive = smsActive)
    userProfile.code2Factor = pyotp.random_base32()
    userProfile.forCompanyId = for_company_id
    userProfile.main_updated = datetime.datetime.now()
    userProfile.save()
    return userProfile
```

Then I do it as follows:

```
user_profile = initialize(input.user.username, password, '', input.title, input.user.first_name, input.user.last_name, input.telephone, input.mobile, sms_active)
user_profile.user.groups.set([Group.objects.get(id=gr.id) for gr in input.groups])
user_profile.cultureMajor = input.cultureMajor
user_profile.offerTax = input.offerTax if 'offerTax' in input else False
user_profile.user.save()
```

But when I try to create new user I get error as follows:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auth_user_pkey" DETAIL: Key (id)=(21811) already exists.
```

The id `21811` exists in the database but the last one is `25530`.

Why django does not use the first next number for ID?

UPDATE

- User model is standard model from django.
- UserProfile is as follows:

  ```
  class UserProfile(models.Model):
      forCompanyId = 1
      user = models.OneToOneField(to=User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
      title = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
      telephone = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
      mobile = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
      smsActive = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      car_by_car_notification = models.BooleanField(default=True)
      car_by_car_mail = models.BooleanField(default=True)
      daily_digest = models.BooleanField(default=True)
      offer_tax = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      cultureMajor = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=False, default='en')
      cultureMinor = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True)
      modulesBlocked = models.ManyToManyField(to=Module, through='UserModuleBlocked')
      otherEmails = models.CharField(max_length=512, null=True, blank=True)
      otherContact = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
      browser = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
      picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=settings.MEDIA_ROOT, blank=True, null=True)
      code2Factor = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
      mobile2Factor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      authenticator2Factor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      main_user_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
      main_updated = models.DateTimeField(_('date updated on main'), default=timezone.now)
  ```

Comment: can you show user and userprofile model

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Comment: @c.grey Updated.

Comment: @JPG PostgreSQL

Comment: Try to create a dummy user from django-shell as **`User.objects.create(id=25531,username="fooo")`** @Boky

Comment: @JPG That works.

Comment: Should I add that as an answer? @Boky

Comment: @JPG That not answer to the question. It works when I add next id manually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've solved the problem by executing following code:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"auth_permission"','id'), coalesce(max("id"), 1), max("id") IS NOT null) FROM "auth_permission";
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"auth_group_permissions"','id'), coalesce(max("id"), 1), max("id") IS NOT null) FROM "auth_group_permissions";
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"auth_group"','id'), coalesce(max("id"), 1), max("id") IS NOT null) FROM "auth_group";
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"auth_user_groups"','id'), coalesce(max("id"), 1), max("id") IS NOT null) FROM "auth_user_groups";
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"auth_user_user_permissions"','id'), coalesce(max("id"), 1), max("id") IS NOT null) FROM "auth_user_user_permissions";
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"auth_user"','id'), coalesce(max("id"), 1), max("id") IS NOT null) FROM "auth_user";
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 9):

This is not an issue with Django

```
duplicate key violates a unique constraint
```

This message occurs when you create a duplicate key.  In your case, this likely means that the primary key sequence in the table you're working with has become out of sync.  This could be because of a manual import, that is often the case with for me when I have had this issue.  You have to manually reset the primary key index.

I am not sure what your database is, I will share with you the rough Postgres SQL commands I would use to fix it, the first two allow you to see if it is out of sync and the last one will fix it if so.  If this isnt enough/its a different db please comment

```
SELECT MAX('auth_user_pkey') FROM User;   
SELECT nextval('auth_user_key_sequence');

SELECT setval('auth_user_key_sequence', (SELECT MAX(auth_user_pkey) FROM User)+1);
```

Comment: When I execute the second one I get `ERROR: relation "the_primary_key_sequence" does not exist`

Comment: I have been having this same issue. I have the same error as @Boky who has been able to solve this?

Comment: You may use this query to find your 'auth_user_key_sequence' to be inserted above:

    SELECT c.relname FROM pg_class c WHERE c.relkind = 'S';

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was to reset the id in the log.

So you run this
`SELECT id FROM 'the_table_name' order by id desc limit 1;`
The number that is returned you increment by 1. Lets say it's 14, then you set it to 15.
`SELECT setval('public.the_table_name_id_seq', 15);`